# C# web extracting programming. Which libraries, examples and samples?

Tags: c#

I have just started programming and have made a few small applications in C and C#. My understanding is that programming for the web and things related to the web is a very easy task nowadays.

Please note this is for personnel learning, not for rent a coder or any money making.

An application which can run on any Windows platform (even Windows 98).

The application should start automatically at a scheduled time and do the following.

1. Connect to a site which displays stock prices summary (high low current open).
2. Capture the data (excluding the other things in the site.)
3. And save it to disk (an SQL database)

Please note:-

The Internet connection is assumed to be there always.

I do not want to know how to make a database schema or a database.

The stock exchange has no law prohibiting the use of the data provided on its site, but I do not want to mention the name in case I am wrong, but it's for personal private use only.

The data of summary of pricing is arranged in a table such that when copied pasted to MS Excel it automatically forms a table.

What are some steps, guidance, examples and libraries for achieving this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse web pages.